# Return a string from runnable

Tags: android, string, runnable

I'm trying to create an Android Application, but I've a problem with the return of the global variable "tmp2" (String): I've to do a check of tmp2 and if is null for breaking the while cycle. The methods `getInvisibleText` and `getVisibleText` are used to split text in pages. How can I do?

```
public void setText (){
        int i = 0;
        tmp = stringResponse;
        //Log.i("TMP", " 1 " + tmp);

        final TextView tv = new TextView (this);
        final PageTurnLayout flipper = (PageTurnLayout) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        while (i != 15){


            tv.setTextSize(20);
            tv.setPadding(7, 5, 5, 0);
            tv.requestLayout();


            tv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText(tmp);
                    tmp = getInvisibleText(tv);
                    tmp2 = getVisibleText(tv);
                    tv.setText(tmp2);
                }
            });

            Log.i("ifNull", " "+ tmp2);
            flipper.addView(tv);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem -- what doesn't work about your code?

Comment: You need to reconsider your program logic. The various `Runnable.run` methods will be executed somewhat delayed, most likely only after the `while` has finished. A computation done there cannot have impact on the `while`.

Comment: - My idea was to check if tmp was null, to return a boolean, integer or stringvalue from the runnable and make a check before the set of the TextView. How can I reorganize my code?